# gtk_window_set_icon_from_file() not working properly

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to display my icon in my window's title bar. The program compiles and runs fine, but the icon is only being displayed in the launcher.

Here's my main function:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{  
    GtkWidget * window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "My Window");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 600, 600);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_window_set_icon_from_file(GTK_WINDOW(window), "img/icon.png", NULL);

    gtk_widget_show(window);

    g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hey @Brandon did the icon show when you minimized the window? Did you ever figure out how to change the icon in the window frame? I've been trying for a couple months now to no avail :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-icon) for `gtk_window_set_icon()` and friends says,

> This icon is used when the window is minimized (also known as iconified). Some window managers or desktop environments may also place it in the window frame, or display it in other contexts.

So it not required that the icon is displayed in the title bar; that is at the discretion of the window manager in your desktop environment. The default window managers in both Gnome and Unity currently do not do so.